# Making a CSS Grid without float

Tags: css, css-float, grid-layout

As the title would suggest I need to make a CSS Grid without losing *float*, since that would interfere with the *Waypoints JS Plugin*...

Anyway, I stumbled upon `display: inline-block;` but if the boxes in the grid take up 100% of the width of the container this only works if you write all the Code in one Line (**[JSFiddle 1](http://jsfiddle.net/zygnz/1436/)**)

Since my Project is a Template, I can't just force the user to write all his Code in one Line.

Is there any way to solve this problem?

**Udate 1:**

`white-space: nowrap;` doesn't help me either because it screws up all the text within the element (**[JSFiddle 2](http://jsfiddle.net/zygnz/1439/)**)

**Udate 2:**

**[This](http://jsfiddle.net/bQemh/2/)** `font-size: 0;` Solution doesn't help me because i also need text in the Parent Element

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Update:

[Working example on jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/htmled/bQemh/).

Setting a `font-size: 0;` to the parent element, then setting it back to the desired size on the containing element will fix the problem. Also be sure to use `vertical-align: top;` on the containing elements so unequal lines of text will both start at the same position at the top.

Note: if you need the two divs to appear in equal height (due to background colors, image, etc.) you'll need to use the [faux columns technique](http://alistapart.com/article/fauxcolumns).

```
.left {
    background: red;
    height: 140px;
    width: 55%;
    margin: 0 5% 0 0;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 14px;
    vertical-align: top;
}
.right {
    background: orange;
    height: 140px;
    width: 40%;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 14px;
    vertical-align: top;
}
section {
    background: black;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0 0 20px;
    color: #ffffff;
    font-size: 0;
}
```

Fix if the divs do not contain text:

[Working example on jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/htmled/7B9Pp/).

Add `white-space: nowrap;` to the section rule:

```
section {
    background: black;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0 0 20px;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

For more information on the `white-space` property, see: http://www.quirksmode.org/css/whitespace.html

Comment: ha, I was 9 seconds too slow.

Comment: white-space: nowrap; doesn't help me either because it screws up all the text within the element [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Asustaba/zygnz/1439/) but thanks for the answer

Comment: I've updated my answer with a work around, since the divs need to include text.

Comment: Thanks but I also need text in the Parent Element

Comment: Hmmm. How about wrapping the text in the parent element in a new element so you can reset the font properties?

Comment: Yeah I probably have to do that... Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

CSS Tricks has a great article on removing the extra white space when using `inline-block`

http://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/